# How to switch off "Not RRM Network" messages

Tags: debian, raspbian, hostapd, wpa

My system's logs are being swamped by these messages:

```
wpa_supplicant[390]: RRM: Ignoring radio measurement request: Not RRM network
```

I have searched extensively; I've even found the sources for `wpa_supplicant` here: `git clone git://w1.fi/hostap.git`
But I'm not fluent in C and have no clue how to proceed.
Can anybody suggest how I can suppress or avoid these messages or switch off this functionality?

EDIT: This is on Raspbian (Debian flavor for Raspberry Pi) Buster, which has `wpa_supplicant v2.8-devel`. It is communicating with a Fritz!Box AP; I mention this because I'm getting the feeling that could be relevant.

EDIT(2):
as requested:

```
$ ps -f -p $(pgrep wpa_supplicant)
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY      STAT   TIME CMD
root       342     1  0 Jul12 ?        Ss     0:02 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant
root       386     1  0 Jul12 ?        Ss     0:04 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -s -B -P /run/wpa_supplicant.wlan0.pid -i wlan0 -D nl80211,wext -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -C /run/wpa_supplicant
```

Comment: you didn't say anything about your OS system and Versions? Also can you find out how wpa_supplication is being started and it's parameter. It maybe able to reduce the logging level. Or it might be a bug that needs to be reported depending on your operating system.

Comment: Could you edit the question and add the output of: `ps -f -p $(pgrep wpa_supplicant)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decrease the verbosity of `wpa_supplicant` by using `-q` or even `-qq`.

See: https://linux.die.net/man/8/wpa_supplicant